# Draw balls from bin and add more balls after draws

Tags: probability, solution-verification, conditional-probability, balls-in-bins

> A bin contains $r$-many red balls and $s$-many black balls. We draw randomly a ball and afterwards we return the ball into the bin and add $c$-many balls of the color we have previously drawn.
>
> We draw two times, what is the probability that the first ball was black if the second one has been red?

---

Let be $\Omega=\{r,s\}^2$ the sample space and the probability measure:

$P(\{(r,r)\})=\frac{r}{r+s}\frac{r+c}{r+s+c},$
$P(\{(r,s)\})=\frac{r}{r+s}\frac{s}{r+s+c},$
$P(\{(s,r)\})=\frac{s}{r+s}\frac{r}{r+s+c},$
$P(\{(s,s)\})=\frac{s}{r+s}\frac{s+c}{r+s+c}.$

Now we simply collect all the elements that correspond to the event we are looking for:

$P($first ball black $\mid$ second ball red $)=\frac{P(\{(s,r)\})}{P(\{(r,r)\})+P(\{(s,r)\})}=\dots=\frac{s}{r+c+s}.$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is being asked is

P(first ball black | second ball red)

= P(first black $\cap$ second red)/ P(second red)

= $\dfrac{\text{P(first black $\cap$ second red)}}{\text{P(first black $\cap$ second red) + P(first red $\cap$ second red)}}$

$ = {\dfrac{s}{s+r}}{\dfrac{r}{s+r+c}}\over{{\dfrac{s}{s+r}}{\dfrac{r}{s+r+c}}+{\dfrac{r}{s+r}}{\dfrac{r+c}{s+r+c}}}$ $= \dfrac{s}{s+r+c}$

Answer (score 1):

The "restricted sample space" is

$$ \Omega' = \{s,r\}^2/\{(r,s),(s,s)\} $$

We removed all the sets corresponding to the second ball having been black, since we are given that the second ball is red.

The measure of $\Omega'$ is $\frac{r}{r+s}$ so the probability that the first ball was black is the measure of $\{(s,r)\}$ divided by the measure of $\Omega'$ which gives us

$$P(\{(s,r)\})|\{(*,r)\}) = \frac{s}{r+s}\frac{r}{r+s+c}\times\frac{r+s}{r}$$
$$ =\frac{s}{r+s+c}$$

Which is indeed the same answer as what you got, but you had a $P(\{(s,s)\})$ in the denominator, which was probably a typo and should have been $P(\{(r,r)\})$?

Comment: No it is not a typo. The denominator is the event $P($first ball black$)$; it's just the definition of the conditional probability.

Comment: Then I think you have the definition mixed up, the probability that the first ball was red given that the second ball was red, should have as numerator the probability of first black and second red, and in the denominator all the ways in which the second ball can be red, we were given that the second ball was red, so we need to "enforce" this constraint by considering only events corresponding to the constraint

Comment: Ah ok, I got it, you are right. I have misunderstood the conditional probability. I have edited my question.